# Table A's PK is being referenced by Table B's FK. Cannot drop Table A's PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, star-schema

MS SQL Server

I'm making a star schema. I've set the `PK's` and `FK` for my tables and am now trying to write a procedure that will drop the constraints, truncate the tables, add the constraints again, and then repopulate the tables. When I try to drop the constraints I receive the error:

"The constraint `PK_TIMEDIM` is being referenced by table `SalesFactTable`, foreign key constraint `FK_SALESFACTTABLE`. Could not drop constraint."

**EDIT:** One problem solved. Another found. I receive the same error except now there are mysterious, auto-generated `FK's` such as `FK__SalesFact__CUST___19DFD96B`.

Please show me what I'm doing wrong.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[A11]
AS
BEGIN

--Drop constraints
ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SALESFACTTABLE

ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_SALESFACTTABLE

ALTER TABLE TimeDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TIMEDIM

ALTER TABLE CustomerDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERDIM

ALTER TABLE PartDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PARTDIM

--Truncate tables
TRUNCATE TABLE TimeDim
TRUNCATE TABLE CustomerDim
TRUNCATE TABLE PartDim
TRUNCATE TABLE SalesFactTable

--Add constraints
ALTER TABLE TimeDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TIMEDIM PRIMARY KEY (TIME_ID)

ALTER TABLE CustomerDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERDIM PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)

ALTER TABLE PartDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PARTDIM PRIMARY KEY (PART_ID)

ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SALESFACTTABLE FOREIGN KEY (TIME_ID) REFERENCES TimeDim (TIME_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CustomerDim (CUST_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PART_ID) REFERENCES PartDim (PART_ID)

ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SALESFACTTABLE PRIMARY KEY (TIME_ID, CUST_ID, PART_ID)
```

Comment: Well, PK is likely a primary key and there are foreign key constraints referencing it. You would need to change the order so that the Foreign Key constraints are dropped first?

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I will try to remember that order is important in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Foreign keys are referenced by the Primary key, so you are not allowed to remove the primary key before removing the Foreign Key constraint.
so, you need to remove the foreign key first to remove the Primary key constraint from a table.

**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[A11]
AS
BEGIN
  --Drop FK constraints
ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SALESFACTTABLE
    --Drop PK constraints
ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_SALESFACTTABLE

ALTER TABLE TimeDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TIMEDIM

ALTER TABLE CustomerDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERDIM

ALTER TABLE PartDim
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PARTDIM

--Truncate tables
TRUNCATE TABLE TimeDim
TRUNCATE TABLE CustomerDim
TRUNCATE TABLE PartDim
TRUNCATE TABLE SalesFactTable

--Add constraints
ALTER TABLE TimeDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TIMEDIM PRIMARY KEY (TIME_ID)

ALTER TABLE CustomerDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERDIM PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)

ALTER TABLE PartDim
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PARTDIM PRIMARY KEY (PART_ID)

ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SALESFACTTABLE FOREIGN KEY (TIME_ID) REFERENCES TimeDim (TIME_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CustomerDim (CUST_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PART_ID) REFERENCES PartDim (PART_ID)

ALTER TABLE SalesFactTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SALESFACTTABLE PRIMARY KEY (TIME_ID, CUST_ID, PART_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to successfully drop the constraints I created, but now I'm receiving the same error except with mysterious, auto-generated(?) `FK's` such as `FK__SalesFact__CUST___19DFD96B`.

Comment: can you debug the store procedure??? 
and see in which par of the sp you are getting this error??

Comment: The debugger failed to start because I'm denied execute permission. :(

Comment: It's strange. The new error does not occur when I drop the `PK_TIMEDIM`, but it does when I try to drop `PK_CUSTOMERDIM` and `PK_PARTDIM`. I'm not sure why it seems to be treating them differently.

Comment: Ok. The SalesFactTable was somehow related to both the CustomerDim and PartDim tables twice. That may have been part of the problem...